# click on "download" link using JQuery doesn't download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link with href and download attributes:

```
  <a id="lnk" href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,1%2C2%2C3" download="my_file.csv">click to download</a>
```

When I click on it (in Chrome for example) a csv file "my_file.csv" is downloaded as supposed.

Now I want to be able to cause this action programmatically. So using JQuery I am trying to do:

```
$('#lnk').click();
```

or

```
$('#lnk').trigger("click");
```

but the file is not downloaded.

Here is the code:
http://jsbin.com/yereg/3/edit

I could copy the link address from the link and then just use window.open:

```
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,1%2C2%2C3');
```

but this way I can't set the file name (link does by `download="my_file.csv"` attribute). This solution is fine if there is a way to set the file name.

Remark: in my case Chrome and Firefox should be supported. I don't care about the rest of the browsers.

Comment: It's a security problem to automate a "user initiated" click event. Browser clients prevent this. I would suggest saving it to the server, send user to new window, then serve the file to the client.

Comment: @StaticVoid It's not a security problem at all. It's a jQuery "problem"

Comment: If you faced the same problem - you are welcome to use serverless CsvGeneretor: https://github.com/AlexLibs/client-side-csv-generator

Answer (score 31, accepted):

from the jquery documentation:

> The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events:
>
> The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element.
>   The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

You could resort to calling the JavaScript native event, through

```
$('#lnk').get(0).click();
```

Or safer:

```
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
if (lnk) {
    lnk.click();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Out of curiosity, I had a look at the jQuery sources how it's done. It turns out that they prevent the native click event of the browser on links in particular on purpose, see the following excerpt from the `events.js` in the latest jQuery version (2.1.x), especially the comment:

```
click: {
    [...]

    // For cross-browser consistency, don't fire native .click() on links
    _default: function( event ) {
        return jQuery.nodeName( event.target, "a" );
    }
},
```

Comment: I tried a few codes and this is only one that worked. 10x!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('#lnk')[0].click()`

JS :

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
  $('#lnk')[0].click();
});
```